# How to run Laravel 5.4 from Apache localhost instead of artisan?

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

I am working on a web application project with Laravel 5.4.21, PHP 7 and Apache 2.4 on Windows 10.

When I run Laravel using 'php artisan serve' command, it runs fine. But if I run from apache htdocs, it shows following errors:

```
FatalThrowableError in Encrypter.php line 130: Call to undefined function openssl_decrypt()
```

But I have OpenSSL enabled in php.ini.

I do not have Xampp. I have searched some solutions, but they do not work.

Comment: Run `php -m` to see if the openssl package is loaded.

Comment: Running php -m command shows openssl in php modules.

Comment: Hmm you might have a different php.ini for CLI versus server. What if you create a page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then hit it from a browser? Does it show openssl is loaded?

Comment: phpinfo() is not showing openssl. But I have uncommented openssl in php.ini file. Still not showing.

Comment: The output of phpinfo() should also show you what ini file is being parsed -- it's probably not the one you think it is.

Comment: Are you using WAMP?

Comment: No, I am not using WAMP.

Comment: Is there any solution?